# Не работает повторная вставка разметки на страницу при формировании ее через class

Tags: javascript

```js
//abstract-view.js

class AbstractView {
  constructor() {
    if (new.target === AbstractView) {
      throw new Error(`Can't instantiate AbstractView, only concrete one`);
    }
  }

  get template() {
    throw new Error(`Template is required`);
  }

  render() {
    const wrapper = document.createElement(`div`);
    wrapper.insertAdjacentHTML(`afterbegin`, this.template);
    console.log(this._element);
    
    return wrapper;
  }

  bind(element) {

  }

  get element() {
    if (this._element) {
      return this._element;
    }
    this._element = this.render();
    this.bind(this._element);
    return this._element;
  }
}

// greeting-view.js
// import AbstractView from '../abstract-view.js';

class GreetingView extends AbstractView {
  get template() {
    return `<div class="greeting central--blur">
    <div class="greeting__logo"><img src="img/logo_big.png" width="201" height="89" alt="Pixel Hunter"></div>
    <h1 class="greeting__asterisk">*</h1>
    <div class="greeting__challenge">
      <h3>Текст</h3>
      <p>Текст<br>
        Текст<br>
        Текст<br>
        Текст<br>
        Текст</p>
    </div>
    <div class="greeting__continue"><span><img src="img/arrow_right.svg" width="64" height="64" alt="Next"></span></div>
  </div>`;
  }

  bind() {
    const arrow = this.element.querySelector(`.greeting__continue > span > img`);

    arrow.addEventListener(`click`, this.onClick);
  }

  onClick() {

  }

}

//greeting.js
/*
import {
  showScreen,
  removeScreen
} from '../util.js';
import GreetingView from './greeting-view.js';
import rulesView from './../rules/rules.js';
import headerView from '../header/header.js';
*/

const greetingView = new GreetingView();

greetingView.onClick = () => {
  console.log(1);
};

document.body.appendChild(greetingView.element);
console.log(greetingView.element);
```

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть класс AbstractView, который содержит общие методы для формирования разметки экрана приложения и последующей ее вставки на страницу. Логика приложения заключается в том, что по нажатию на кнопку далее у меня переключается экран и, соответственно, изменяется разметка. Все успешно отрабатывает, разметка вставляется, но, при определенном условии, мне необходимо использовать уже отработанную разметку повторно и тут возникает проблема: мой класс отдает мне пустой див (мой wrapper из метода render) без разметки внутри. В чем проблема, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: Хм, возможно проблема в том, каким образом ты меняешь этот элемент. Хотелось бы увидеть пример, где ты создаешь экземпляр этого класса и используешь его элемент.

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Попробуй отладить геттер элемента

Comment: Консоль лог туда какой-нибудь можно, если нет возможности отлаживать

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, я пробовал консоль лог геттера, и почему то он мне возвращает всегда пустой див, причем два раза

Comment: Мда, тогда не могу найти ошибок, моего опыта тут не хватит

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, и на этом спасибо!

Comment: Хотя, погоди ка

Comment: А ты рендер не переопределил?

Comment: Попробуй отладить также рендер и геттер темплейта

Comment: Попробуй может что-то кроме `insertAdjacentHTML`, может этот метод не везде правильно срабатывает

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, вообще не понимаю, рендер мне тоже пустой див отдает. ИннерХТМЛ пытался использовать - тот же самый результат.

Comment: Блин, кажется я придумал, что может быть не так, надо побольше про это почитать. Может `wrapper` надо сделать не `const`, а `let` или `var` в рендере

Comment: Но это странно, вроде бы wrapper должен быть mutable

Comment: @alex, я отредактировал сниппет чтобы его можно было запустить. Попробуй поправить его так, чтобы ошибка воспроизводилась

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, в данном случае `const`/`let`/`var` для `wrapper` ничем не отличаются

Comment: @Grundy ну да, не должно отличаться, я на случай вдруг, но в чем тут тогда проблема?

Comment: @АндрейГригорьев, без воспроизводимого примера сложно сказать, возможно в какой-то момент, возможно даже сторонним кодом, напрямую стирается содержимое элемента, а так как в классе это никак не отслеживается - он продолжает возвращать пустую обертку

Comment: @Grundy, судя по тому, что я поотключал все экраны и оставил только код в greeting-view, greeting и abstract-view, а рендер все равно возвращает пустой див, то все-таки дело в коде. Но самое интересное, что мой экран с этим "пустым дивом" все равно отрисовывается.

Comment: @alex, не совсем понял, если отрисовывается - значит див не пустой. Следовательно либо ты что-то не то проверяешь либо одно из двух :). Попробуй сделать так, чтобы в сниппет было явно видно проблему

Comment: @Grundy, В самый низ добавил console.log(greetingView.element); И консоль, как я понимаю, выводит пустой див(три точки означают пустоту в данном случае?). Вот такая же проблема и у меня в коде.

Comment: @alex, не, открой консоль браузера - там видно что див нормальный :) просто для вывода в сниппете элементы html по разному сериализуются

Comment: @Grundy, да, вижу.

Comment: @Grundy, ура, с общей помощью разобрался в чем дело. Спасибо! Код, приводивший к ошибке:
`element.childNodes.forEach((node) => {
      document.body.appendChild(node)
    });`

Как-то очень странно, что такой блок кода мог повлиять на логику переключения экранов.

Comment: Ну так `appendChild` переносит элемент, поэтому у `element` не оставалось детей

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106780/discussion-between-grundy-and-alex).